# My mystyle.css is not working in django index.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

css is not working in django, image and the text are showing, but text didn't get the css effect.
i tried at my best, but failed

I need to get the css effect to the text in the index.html file, please help me

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> first app Static Files </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'mystyle.css' %}"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> This is the photo of Cal</h1>
    <img src="{% static "Images/cal.jpg" %}" width="400" height="400", alt="oh ohhh!!... Cant display image"/>

  </body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
h1{
  color: red,

}

this is linked with index.html, but not working
```

settings.py

```
import os


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")


ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'first_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first_project.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,

]
```

I need to get the css effect to the text in the index.html file,
please help me

everything is ok except this,
all others are ok, model, view, urls, ...etc

Comment: could you share the file structure of your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you got your CSS wrong, put a semi-colon after red

```
h1 {
color: red;
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, it was a simple error, loot my long time, thanks alot